# looping through dictionary inside dictionary in jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, dictionary

I'm trying to set values to table containing textboxes in each cell. For instance a table having a first column containing names, and rest of the columns containing textboxes to add marks of the given assignment for individual students. For that I used dictionary to hold given marks by the instructor and when the page is load, the marks are set to the relevant textboxes. however my iteration over Dictionary in jquery doesn't seem to be really working. I'm missing somewhere in loop. Below is my code.

```
public class StudentAssignments
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public Models.Assignment assignment { get; set; }
        public Models.User user { get; set; }
        public DateTime? SubmissionDate { get; set; }
        public string Result { get; set; }
        public Models.File assignmentfiles {get;set;}
    }

public class Assignment
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string batchid { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> batchnumber { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }
        public Models.File file { get; set; }
    }


 public class File
    {
        public string strId { get; set; }
        public string strName { get; set; }
        public string strPath { get; set; }
        public string strSize { get; set; }
    }
```

**InstructorController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
         public ActionResult AssignedStudents(string id)
    {
            //Get Student Assignments
        Models.StudentAssignments studentAssignment = new Models.StudentAssignments();
        Context.Assignment contAssignment = new Context.Assignment();
        CreateUser contUser = new CreateUser();

        Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<Models.StudentAssignments>>> dict = 
            new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<Models.StudentAssignments>>>();


        var studentslist = contStudent.getAllStudentBatchList().Where(p => p.batchId == id).Select(p => p.studentId).ToList();
        var assignmentid = contAssignment.lstAssignment().Where(p => p.batchid == id).Select(p=>p.Id).ToList();

        foreach(var items in studentslist)
        {
            dict.Add(items.ToString(), new Dictionary<string, List<Models.StudentAssignments>>());

            foreach (var item1 in assignmentid)
            {
                dict[items].Add(item1.ToString(), GetStudentFiles(items, item1));
            }
        }

        ViewBag.StudentAssignment = dict;
        }


private List<Models.StudentAssignments> GetStudentFiles(string stdid, string assgnid)
        {
            Context.Assignment contAssignment = new Context.Assignment();
            CreateUser contuser = new CreateUser();
            List<Models.StudentAssignments> lstassgn = new List<Models.StudentAssignments>();

            var details = (from t1 in contAssignment.GetStudentAssignments()
                                                        join
                                                        t2 in contAssignment.GetStudentAssignmentsFiles() on
                                                        t1.Id equals t2.assignment.Id
                                                        join t3 in contuser.GetAllUsers() on t1.user.Id equals t3.Id
                                                        where t1.assignment.Id == assgnid && t1.user.Id == stdid
                                                        select new { t1,t2,t3 }).ToList();

            foreach (var item in details)
            {
                Models.StudentAssignments assignment = new Models.StudentAssignments();
                assignment.assignment = new Models.Assignment();
                assignment.Id = item.t1.Id;
                assignment.Result = item.t1.Result;
                assignment.assignmentfiles = new Models.File();
                assignment.assignmentfiles.strId = item.t2.Id;
                assignment.assignmentfiles.strPath = item.t2.assignmentfiles.strPath;
                assignment.user = new Models.User();
                assignment.user.Id = item.t3.Id;
                assignment.user.FirstName = item.t3.FirstName;
                assignment.user.LastName = item.t3.LastName;
                lstassgn.Add(assignment);
            }

            return lstassgn;
        }
```

**AssignedStudents.cshtml**

```
<div class="col-md-12">
         <h2>Submitted Assignments</h2>

         <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover" id="tbl">
             <tr>
                 <th>
                     Name
                 </th>
                 <th>
                     Assignment 1
                 </th>

             </tr>

             @foreach (var item in ViewBag.StudentAssignment)
             {

                 bool flag = true;

                <tr class="item">

                    @foreach (var item1 in item.Value)
                    {
                        foreach (var item2 in item1.Value)
                        {
                            if (flag == true)
                            {
                                <td>
                                    @item2.user.FirstName
                                </td>

                                flag = false;
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                        <td>
                            @foreach (var item2 in item1.Value)
                            {
                                <a href="@item2.assignmentfiles.strPath"><img src="#" /></a>
                            }


@foreach (var item2 in item1.Value)
                        {
                            if (item2.Result != null && item2.Result != "Pending")
                            {
                                <div><input type="text" value="@item2.Result" class="txtbox" id=@Guid.NewGuid().ToString()  disabled="disabled"/></div>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <div><input type="text" class="txtbox" id=@Guid.NewGuid().ToString() /></div>
                            }
                            <input type="hidden" id="stdassgnid" value="@item2.Id" />
                            break;
                        }
                        </td>
                    }
                </tr>
             }
         </table>

         <input type="button" id="saveResult" value="Save Result" class="btn btn-success" />

    </div>
```

**Edited:-** 
Since I've managed to pass the results in the required textboxes. I'm here surrounded by another issue which is the next assignment submission. The first column contains the submitted marks already, and this time instructor would carry out the marking of the next assignment. Therefore, The system would look for the next column as the previous column already contains marks.

```
$("#saveResult").click(function () {

        $("#tbl tr.item").each(function () {
            $(this).find("input.txtbox").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            var Mkrs = $(this).find("input.txtbox").val();
            var Id = $(this).find("#stdassgnid").val();

            alert(Mkrs)

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("UpdateResult", "Assignment")',
                data: { Marks: Mkrs, studentAssgnId: Id},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {

                    if(data.message!=null)
                    {
                        alert(data.message)
                    }
                }
            })

        });
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: And why are you making an ajax call anyway instead of just passing a model to the view?

Comment: The jquery loop is actually not looping till the length of values the dictionary contains.

Comment: Let me edit my question, I've done some changes.

Comment: Its crazy to be making an ajax call for this - you basically say to the client  _here is some view, but its not the complete because I forgot to send the rest, so waste some more time making another call to get the rest of the data_

Comment: And you will find this a lot easier if you use a view model rather than a `Dictionary`(s).

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've just updated my question, and yes This time i passed my model directly to view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164449/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-user100020).